# DataTemplates and DataContext inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, datacontext

I have the following bits of XAML:

```
Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:ProductBuilderVm/>
</Window.DataContext>

<UNNECESSARY DETAILS SNIP>

<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabViewModels}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTabVm}">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ProductDefinitionVm}">
                <view:ProductDefinition></view:ProductDefinition>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:CouplingsViewVm}">
                <view:CouplingsView></view:CouplingsView>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:RulesVm}">
                <view:RulesView></view:RulesView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>
    </TabControl>
```

My idea here was to create 1 main ViewModel (ProductBuilderVm) to serve as the 'parent' to the three ViewModels in the TabControl. I thought I had this working, but now that I'm trying to communicate things between these child Vm's, I came to the realization that they're each a separate instance with no relation to each other.

How can I refactor this window to have 1 ProductBuilderVm, with 3 child Vm's beneath it? The goal is to pull data from the first child for use in the second.

Thanks!

Comment: You could just have the parentVm store references to the 3 child vm's also

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of to achieve passing values between ViewModels is to use something like the MVVM Light Messenger class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745866.aspx.

You register each ViewModel to receive messages:

```
//Register for custom typed message
Messenger.Default.Register<MyMessageType>(this, OnMyMessageTypeReceived);
//Register for string messages
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, NotificationMessageReceived);
```

Then you can send a Message to a ViewModel using:

```
//String message
Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("SetupMyProductDefinitionVm"));
//Custom typed message sent to ViewModel of specific type
var myMsg = new MyMessageType();
Messenger.Default.Send<MyMessageType, ProductDefinitionVm>(myMsg);
```